# Read the HTML table data into an array with JavaScript / PrototypeJS

Tags: javascript, html-table, prototypejs

Please, consider the following example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aadBGJ?editors=1111

I'm trying to read the table into the JS object, but somehow it only stores the last line.

I get:

```
{
ean: "test3",
sku: "0003"
}
```

I want to get:

```
[
{
    ean: "test1",
    sku: "0001"
},
{
    ean: "test2",
    sku: "0002"
},
{
    ean: "test3",
    sku: "0003"
},
]
```

Your input is very much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solution found (credits to https://gist.github.com/WickyNilliams/9252235#file-parsetable-js). I updated the codepen.